# my image in docker hub why does not appear in the search engine? neither with the docker search command

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I pushed an image, it can be seen in my profile, you can do a pull, but in the docker hub search engine it does not appear, either with the docker search command

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

docker hub add images to the search engine every 24 hours, So, I only had to wait 1 day for searched in docker hub my imagen

Answer (score 1):

You most likely pushed your image to your private repo.
[Docs on publishing images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/publish/publish/)

Comment: It is assumed he already published it as public, which is the default.